# Row in database is NULL and I dont know why

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller to add some data on my database. All is working excepted one row.

Here is my code :

View :

```
    <div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Logo</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="logo">
```

Controller :

```php
Vpns::create([
    'title' => $request->title,
    'intro' => $request->intro,
    'content' => $request->content,
    'jeux' => $jeux,
    'chine' => $request->chine,
    'torrent' => $request->torrent,
    'netflix' => $request->netflix,
    'nolog' => $request->nolog,
    'securite' => $request->securite,
    'paiement' => $request->paiement,
    'systemes' => $request->systemes,
    'appareils' => $request->appareils,
    'lien' => $request->lien,
    'url' => $request->url,
    'meilleur_prix' => $request->meilleur_prix,
    'duree_abo' => $request->duree_abo,
    'logo' => $request->logo]
);
```

In my form I put a string in row "logo" but in database it appears as "NULL", I don't know why...

Migrations :

```php
public function up()
{
  Schema::table('vpns', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->string('logo')->nullable();
  });
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: are these fields all set as "fillable" on the model?

Comment: it was it ! thank you

Comment: can you give the full code in the view (form to save the data) ?

Answer (score 0):

As @lagbox already said, you should make sure that the `$fillable` attribute in your `Vpns` model contains the correct fields.

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts):

> However, before using the create method, you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded property on your model class